# Escaping strings containing single quotes in PowerShell ready for SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am trying to run the following query, which takes someone's name and attempts to insert it into an SQL Server database table.

```
$name = "Ronnie O'Sullivan"

$dataSource = "127.0.0.1"
$database = "Danny"
$connectionString = "Server=$dataSource;Database=$database;Integrated Security=True;"

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()

$query = "INSERT INTO People(name) VALUES('$name')"

$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()

$connection.Close()
```

The problem I am facing is that the single quote is causing an issue in my query. The query is being executed as

```
INSERT INTO People(name) VALUES('Ronnie O'Sullivan')
```

which causes an SQL syntax error.

My question is how do I escape my $name variable so that it renders on the SQL side.

One solution is to do a find and replace on my $name variable, find: ' replace: ''

```
$name.Replace("'", "''")
```

Is there a more elegant solution out there, or a function that I can't seem to find?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use quotename in your query? I.e.: INSERT INTO People(name) VALUES(QUOTENAME($name))

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try to update your code to to use a parametrised value that will cope with quotes in a string:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO People(name) VALUES(@name)"

$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$command.Parameters.Add("@name", $name)  -- | Out-Null (may be required on the end)
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I'm not experienced with powershell but referenced this post for a [parametrised query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266758/how-to-pass-the-parameter-in-sql-query-from-powershell):

Comment: +1 *Always* use prepared statements (or parametrized queries, as Microsoft calls them).

Comment: And how exactly should one do this when building a 1,000 line insert statement?

Comment: @Pxtl I'd start by looking at why you have a 1000 line insert statement...

Comment: @Tanner ETL and I don't hate myself enough to use SSIS.

Comment: @Pxtl You build a datatable, put it in a dataadapter, and tell it to run 1,000 inserts. Wrap the whole thing in a transaction and it will perform just fine.

Comment: Good advice, but I think the  syntax of the `Parameters.Add()` call (which you've taken from the linked answer) won't work. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add) suggest that you must use something like: `$command.Parameters.Add([System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter]::new("name", $name))`

Answer (score 1):

**[Tanner's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21911377/45375) is definitely the most robust and *secure* solution**, because using a [parameterized / prepared statement (query) eliminates any possibility of a [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

However, **in this constrained case**, where you want to **insert a value into a single-quoted SQL string (`'...'`)**, you can get away with simply **doubling any *embedded* `'` characters in the value**:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO People(name) VALUES('$($name -replace "'", "''")')"
```

The above uses PowerShell's [string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) via `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), to embed an expression that uses the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) to double all embedded `'` instances in the value of `$name`.

Note: You could also use `$name.Replace("'", "''")` above, which performs better in this simple case, but PowerShell's `-replace` operator is generally preferable, not only for being PowerShell-native, but for offering superior abilities, because it is regex-based and supports array as its LHS - see [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6842#issuecomment-387877490).