# Cannot escape $ in table name within SQL query in powershell script

Tags: sql, powershell, escaping

I am trying to run a SQL query in my powershell script. Unfortunately some of the tables in the database contain $'s. in this case one of the tables is

> ServiceManager.dbo.MT_System$WorkItem$Incident

without any thing changed the table in the SQL Query becomes

> ServiceManager.dbo.MT_System

If i use the standard escape character of ' it then becomes

> ServiceManager.dbo.MT_System''

If i add another $ it becomes

> ServiceManager.dbo.MT_System'}WorkItem'}Incident

I tried surrounding the $ with qoutes which results in

> ServiceManager.dbo.MT_System'$'WorkItem'$'Incident

any help would be apreciated

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911112/escaping-strings-containing-single-quotes-in-powershell-ready-for-sql-query and parameterized queries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query

Comment: just figured it out i was using ' instead of `

Comment: @RobynH Feel free to post a self-answer!

Answer (score 0):

These `$` characters can be properly escaped in PowerShell by using the backtick (`` ` ``) character, such as: `` ServiceManager.dbo.MT_System`$WorkItem`$Incident ``.