# Escape single quote when inserting into SQL Server from PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the following code:

```
$ItemsToItemGroups | Where-Object { $_.ItemGroupId -ne $null } | ForEach-Object {
    $Query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Items (ArticleNumber, ArticleNameDE, ArticleNameFR, ItemGroupId) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')" -f $_.ArticleNumber, $_.ArticleNameDE, $_.ArticleNameFR, $_.ItemGroupId
    Invoke-SqlCmd -ConnectionString $NewDBConnectionString -Query $Query
}
```

My problem is, that the string that gets inserted into the `ArticleNameFR` column sometimes is a string like this `à l'anglaise` - that breaks the insert statement, because of the single quote.

Is there an easy way how I can escape it in my statement so it doesn't break the operation?

I insert around 3000 rows and 95% work perfectly, but some throw an error because of the above.

I *could* simply replace the `'` character in the string before I read it into the DB but I'd rather not do that because the data wouldn't be 100% correct then.

Comment: Single quotes are escaped by doubling them - or more correctly using parameters.

Comment: @DaleK thanks, that was easy, i just did `$_.ArticleNameFR -replace "'","''"`

Comment: Indeed, @SimonS - please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64454230/45375